# non-copying istringstream

Tags: c++, istream, istringstream

So `istringstream` copies the contents of a string when initialised, e.g

```
string moo("one two three four");
istringstream iss(moo.c_str());
```

I was wondering if there's a way to make `std::istringstream` use the given `c_str` as its buffer without copying things. This way, it won't have to copy large bits of memory before passing the `std::istringstream&` to functions that take `istream&` as an argument.

What I've been trying to do is convert some functions which only take `std::ifstream&` arguments (they're mostly parsers) into taking `istream&` as well. Would I have to make my own `istream` subclass for this?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786816/how-to-create-c-istringstream-from-a-char-array-with-null0-characters/2786872#2786872) for a way to do it (basically identical to @Charles's solution, but wrapping a `istream` around it for convenience).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's fairly trivial to write a basic `std::streambuf` class that reads from a given memory area. You can then construct an `istream` from this and read from that.

[initializing a C++ std::istringstream from an in memory buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448467/initializing-a-c-stdistringstream-from-an-in-memory-buffer/1449527#1449527)

Note that the lifetime of the buffer pointed to be `c_str()` is very limited, though, and there's no guarantee that a call to `c_str()` want cause some copying although I don't know of any implementations where it does.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that, will give that a try. It looks a lot simpler than what I imagined it would be :)

Comment: In my case this definitely doesn't work the same as `istringstream`, solution by @Riot bellow does work though as expected. In my case code updates get pointer in the istringstream while reading using `seekg`. In other words proper solution would require seekpos overload as well to match behavior of `ostreingstream`

Answer (score 9):

Using `istringstream` is not a satisfactory solution, because this copies the entire buffer.

A previous answer suggests the deprecated `istrstream`, but as this generates warnings and may be removed in future, a better solution is to use [boost::iostreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html):

```
boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::array_source> stream(moo.c_str(), moo.size());
```

This avoids copying the buffer in the same way `istrstream` did, and saves you having to write your own stream class.

Answer (score 3):

the deprecated `istrstream` supports this feature.

```
#include <string>
#include <strstream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string moo = "one two three four";
    istrstream istr(const_cast<char*>(moo.c_str()),moo.size());
    std::string line;
    while(!istr.fail() && !istr.eof()){
        getline(istr,line,' ');
        cout << line << "_";
    }
    // prints: one_two_three_four_
}
```

Comment: @sbi: my bad, i did some tests with strstream first, was a leftover from that, well its fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

There's only a copy because the parameter you pass, a `const char*`, requires conversion to the argument type of the [istringstream constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istringstream/istringstream/).

Just pass in the `string` without calling `c_str()`.

```
istringstream iss(moo);
```

Well ok, that doesn't prevent copying completely, but it eliminates an unnecessary copy.  To completely eliminate the copy, you'd have to rewrite [`std::stringbuf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringbuf/), which specifically avoids working directly on the `string` you give it.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what a std::string does.  According to 27.2.1/1 `The class basic_istringstream<charT,traits,Allocator> ... uses a basic_stringbuf<charT,traits,Allocator> object to control the associated storage.`  Since the class must use an object it must copy construct the string into that object.

So the real question is not whether a `stringstream` copies the contents, but whether copy constructing a string will copy the contents or implement some sort of copy-on-write scheme.

Answer (score 0):

After a few days of searching and trying various methods including scnlib, sscanf, istringstream, etc., maybe I found the answer. If you care about parsing performance, you should use the `from_chars` family of functions in [charsconv header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/charconv) that were added to C++17. This is the only reasonable solution for fast parsing of `string_view` in C++.

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars):

> Unlike other parsing functions in C++ and C libraries, std::from_chars is locale-independent, non-allocating, and non-throwing. Only a small subset of parsing policies used by other libraries (such as std::sscanf) is provided. This is intended to allow the fastest possible implementation that is useful in common high-throughput contexts such as text-based interchange (JSON or XML).

The problems with the other methods are as follows:

**[scnlib](https://github.com/eliaskosunen/scnlib):** I've found that its performance is related to the length of the incoming string, and that even when you're only parsing an integer, passing in a long string causes a [linear performance degradation](https://github.com/eliaskosunen/scnlib/issues/89). This is unacceptable for scenarios requiring high performance.

**istringstream:** As the question says, it can't handle scopes and inevitably requires a copy at initialization time.

**sscanf:** A C-style null terminated string is necessary, while some implementations may likewise cause performance problems according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf).