# How to feed Boost.PropertyTree with a string, not a file?

Tags: c++, xml, boost, input, boost-propertytree

Boost has a [tutorial on how to load XML from a file](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/tutorial.html). How do I feed it with a string that I either create in code or receive from a user (e.g. with `cin`)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Wrap the string in an [`istringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istringstream/).

Answer (score 13):

Heres some code that works for me...

```
// Create an empty property tree object
ptree xmlTree;

// Read the XML config string into the property tree. Catch any exception
try {
  stringstream ss; ss << xmlConfigString;
  read_xml(ss, xmlTree);
}
catch (xml_parser_error &e) {
  LOGERROR ("Failed to read config xml " << e.what());
}
catch (...) {
  LOGERROR ("Failed to read config xml with unknown error");
}
```

Answer (score 10):

The other answers are non-ideal, because using `istringstream` needlessly copies the entire buffer.

As an answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122901/non-copying-istringstream/37712858) suggests, you could use the deprecated `istrstream`, but as this generates warnings and may be removed in future, a better solution is to use [boost::iostreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html):

```
boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::array_source> stream(moo.c_str(), moo.size());
boost::property_tree::read_json(stream, tree);
```

This avoids needlessly copying the buffer in the same way `istrstream` did (which can be a considerable problem, if your input buffer is large), and saves you having to write your own stream class.