# How to find only the content of a specific HTML tag using c++?

Tags: html, c++, tags, html-parsing, html-parser

I'm writing a program where into a `string` I've the code of an **HTML page**. Now, I need to get the text between the `<article>` tag. My html page contain more than one *article* tag, so I need to get the text of the different *article tags*

An example of the article tag is:

```
<article class="item" data-recipe="119726">
        <a class="loopimg pvideo" href="http://www.cookaround.com/ricetta/pasta-frolla-4.html" title="Leggi: Pasta frolla"><img src="http://cdn.cook.stbm.it/thumbnails/ricette/119/119726/hd400x225.jpg" alt="Leggi: Pasta frolla" /></a>
        <h3><a href="http://www.cookaround.com/ricetta/pasta-frolla-4.html" title="Leggi: Pasta frolla">Pasta frolla</a></h3>
        <ul><li>Difficoltà <span>bassa</span></li><li class="costo">Costo <span>basso</span></li><li>Realizzazione <span>10 min</span></li></ul>
    </article>
```

So, I need to get the `title="Leggi: Pasta frolla"` of every *article tag* where the `title` is different for each tag.

How can I do this using c++?

Comment: Did you try `std::string::find` and `std::string::substring`?

Comment: but for more than one article tag? I'va an undefined number of article tag @NathanOliver

Comment: Put the find as a condition of a while loop.

Comment: @NathanOliver how? which variable?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use [Boost](http://www.boost.org/), a very powerful library.

Maybe you have a look at this question
[Parsing XML Attributes with Boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010473/parsing-xml-attributes-with-boost), which should address your problem.

Comment: How can I add **Boost** in Visual Studio 2015? @Cr3at0rX

Comment: A quick search on google gave me this  [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GOhHMS4I9Zw)

Comment: but If don't have a *xml* file but a string containing the html code? However thanks to the link @Cr3at0rX

Comment: Just use the search function. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289086/how-to-feed-boost-propertytree-with-a-string-not-a-file

Comment: I tried to use it but... if I read the string which contain the whole html code I show this error: `expected =` what is the problem? @Cr3at0rX